# batch destroy all in rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a large number of Product objects, that all have an associated "variant" with them. I can't just `delete_all` products because I need the association to be deleted as well.

When I use `Products.all.destroy_all` it freezes and doesn't finish destroy all the products and then it forces me to cancel it and roll it back.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If "variant" records don’t have any dependencies that would have to be deleted from the database use `dependent: :delete_all` instead of `dependent: :destroy`

```
products_count = Product.count

# Determine how many batches need to be run
number_of_iterations = (products_count.to_f / 1000).ceil

(1..number_of_iterations).each do |i|
  Product.limit(1000).delete_all
end
```

When dealing with MASSIVE amounts of data it’s good to batch the deletion. If you delete more than 5,000 rows in a single transaction, your database will lock. This means the entire table is inaccessible by any other running process for the duration of the transaction. This can mean some serious issues for the users of your site while a DELETE is happening.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55914329/1548557 is actually a better option as you can still .each for each batch, and the syntax is more expressive.

Answer (score 15):

For large number of objects and associated 'variant' with them, you have to use destroy_all.

```
Product.all.destroy_all
```

Since destroy_all actually loads the entire relation and then iteratively destroys the records one by one, you can blow your memory gasket very easily. So let's do the right thing by default and do this work in batches of 100 by default and allow you to specify the batch size like so: `destroy_all(batch_size: 100).`

```
Product.destroy_all(batch_size: 100)
```

OR

You can use **in_batches** also

```
Product.in_batches(of: 200).destroy_all
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I was using limit to step through but this makes so much more sense.

Comment: Product.destroy_all(batch_size: 100) no longer works. Conditions argument was removed  in Rails 5.0.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

While `in_batches` is convenient, please keep in mind that it glosses over some details that may affect you.

For 10,000 records there are 10,020 queries:

- 10 queries plucking 1000 integers each
- 10 queries (with 1000 bind variables) selecting 1000 product records each
- 10,000 queries deleting 1 record each

So each id goes from the db to ruby to the db to ruby and back to the db.

One relatively easy optimization is to have `in_batches` fetch the records for you and then manually destroy them. This may be only 10 queries fewer, but those queries are much smaller, sending only 10,020 integers to the server (vs 20,020 before):

```rb
Product.in_batches(of: 1000, load: true) { |records| records.each(&:destroy) }
```

Now, 10,000 records takes 10,010 queries:

- 10 queries fetching 1000 records each (with 2 bind variables)
- 10,000 queries deleting 1 record

---

Since `delete_all` returns the number of records deleted, you don't need to count the number of records up front. You just need to loop until it has no more records to delete. You will be sending 10 bind variables to the server and fetching none. You'll also fetching 0 records and 10 integers from the database:

```rb
while(Product.limit(1000).delete_all == 1000) ; end
# OR
while(Product.limit(1000).delete_all > 0) ; end
```

- 10 queries with 1 bind variable each returning 1 integer.

I provide 2 examples here. The first approach detects a partial batch and aborts. The second approach needs to run the delete query one additional time (which will delete 0 records). It is sometimes more convenient to not have this code know the batch size, so that is why I included the second example.

---

Now you did say that you have an associated second table, which will discourage the `delete_all` solution.

If you are willing to code specifically for the association, and the association is not STI, then you can just delete both manually. I did `Product.all` here, but you could include a `where()` kind of scope if needed. If it is polymorphic, you'll need to add a `:product_type => Product.polymorphic_name`.

```rb
Variant.where(:product_id => Product.all.select(:id)).delete_all
Product.all.delete_all
```

Also, please note I used `select(:id)` and not `pluck(:id)` above. The `select` will create a subquery, and the `pluck` will bring back and then send up all product ids. (not what you want)